# class X : X<T> { } pattern in C# --- what is it used for?

Tags: c#, generics

What is this pattern used for ? note that it is different than the C++ "curiously recurring template pattern".

Comment: Do you mean `class X : T<X>`?  If so, this *is* the curiously recurring template pattern.  Note that if your title is correct, `X` and `X<T>` are actually two different types; we'd need to see an example of such a use.

Comment: Yes, it is the X : X<T> not the CRTP pattern.

Answer (score 4):

Having the generic ancestor class know the actual descendant that inherits from it helps in scenarios where the generic ancestor needs to expose a particular non-generic descendant class as part of the non-generic descendant's result own contract.

One common example is a factory method declared in the generic ancestor:

```
public class Parent<T> 
    where T : Parent<T>, new
{
    public static T Create()
    {
        return new T(); // would be typically something more sophisticated
    }
}

public class Child : Parent<Child>
{
}
```

The primary advantage of this concept is code-deduplication.

Comment: Isn't this just the Curiously Recurring Template pattern again?  The post is asking about class X : X<T>,  not class X : Y<X>....